# Python ctypes behaviour with variable types

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm using a third party python library, that is using ctypes (it uses a dll). I'm not very familiar with ctypes. The lib offers a type definition and a structure definition as given in the minimum example below. I'm trying to assign the member variable `myClassInst.MSGTYPE` the value of the constant `MYConst`. Afterwards I want to check the value with the unittest assertion macro but check fails due to different types. The different types are shown in the output below, too.

I do not understand, why the types differ? What's the correct way to write that piece of code? I'm quite new to Python, so thank you in advance for your support

```
from ctypes import *
import unittest

MyType  = c_ubyte
MYConst = MyType(0xED)

class MyClass (Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ("MSGTYPE", MyType) ]

class myTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        myClassInst = MyClass()
        myClassInst.MSGTYPE = MYConst
        print(type(MYConst))
        print(type(myClassInst.MSGTYPE))
        self.assertEqual(MYConst, myClassInst.MSGTYPE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The output is:

```
<class 'ctypes.c_ubyte'>
<class 'int'>
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test (__main__.myTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mimimumexample.py", line 16, in test
    self.assertEqual(MYConst, myClassInst.MSGTYPE)
AssertionError: c_ubyte(237) != 237

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a ctypes structure, ctypes "helpfully" converts to/from Python objects when reading/writing the member variables, so reading MYConst produces a Python int.

Change `MYConst = MyType(0xED)` to `MyConst = 0xED` and it will work correctly.

(and THANK YOU for a standalone example with unit test!)

Comment: You're welcome. For me, minimum standalone examples are very important. In C++-World I even add online-compiler links, but my friendly question about Python online-compilers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428629/python-online-evaluator-for-code-examples-in-stack-overflow has been closed immediately. Became hard at Stack overflow...

Comment: Unfortunately, the constant is part of the library, too. I can't change it. But nevertheless, the answer is helpful to understand the problem. The class ctypes._SimpleCData.value property helps to return the python int from the constant.